# How to make an api rest with a real url instead localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, proxy, localhost

I'm new to MEAN, I want to know how to make a call to my api but with a real url, I only used api endpoint with localhost like localhost:3000/users/1. I bought a domain in aws as a domain gateway but is as simple as **mydomain.com/users/1** ???. I ask because I dont think is that easy. Or is just using localhost as each device have its own localhost so and the collections are in mlab.. Im doing an app with it is a web application with ionic, angular, node, express and mongodb, I thought it would be necessary to use lambdas and dynamo if cause i bougth the domain gateway but i just want a real domain to make the api call so i can access from everywhere and then manage everything from node, mongo etc instead lambdas, dynamo etc. only have an endpoint that can be accessed from anywhere. It sounds a bit silly the question but I do not know how this works as i just studied this for a short time, people told me about pointing it to the IP address or proxies etc but I have no idea about that. Another thing, regarding to databases I've only seen mongoDB, so to open the connection to mlab would be executing **mongod** and **nodemon ./bin/www** so it stays connected, but obviously I want an app that always listens and has open mlab and with a real url as I said. Can someone guide a little bit on how this should work? Would be appreciated. **THANKS A LOT**

Answer (score 0):

A good first step is Heroku. They have a free hosting level, and since you're building MEAN, you're probably using Express - they make Express deployment very simple.  Once you set up an account and download the CLI tools, you can create an app from the command line and it will assign a domain name (or you can choose your own).  Push your express server to heroku master.  You can  generate an mLab connection as a resource when you set up the app.  copy/paste the mLab url into the server  and you're good to go.

Don't forget to change nodemon back to node in your start script.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things you need to do.

1. Domain name (which you have)
2. Server to run your app (@stever resonse with Heroku is a good start)
3. DNS to point the URL to the IP of the server or where ever you end up hosting the app

As for you connection to mlab. To keep a connection alive, my express apps use this snippet early on to connect to the db.

```html
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`Oooops → ${err.message}`);
});
```

And then with all my models assign the global promise.

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Comment: It may be helpful to point out that in most cases the Domain Registrar will host your DNS records for free and that is where you would update what the domain point at.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mate here are few steps which I follow on each deployment

1. Get a server from any provider like aws or digital ocean.
2. Since It is a Angular + Node project Setup Nginx and pm2 in your server [pm2 production-setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04)! [Nginx Production setup](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)!
3. Nginx is for angular deployment and pm2 is for nodejs.
4. Set up your firewall using utf to allow all ip's or white-list some ip's[check step 4 here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04)!
5. You will have a good running production server now